# Georeferencing raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

Georeferenced raster in the QGIS not filmed the final display by raster footprints.

[image]

Everything is in EPSG 32633.

Path in  GdalToools:

[image]

Red is original footprint for image.

I need rotate image to red area

Any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: Please clarify you question, as it is not clear what is wrong.

Comment: Red is original footprint for image.
I need rotate image to red area.

Comment: Show us what gdalinfo reports about your image.

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS, the Georeferencer tool found under the Raster menu is the way to properly register an aerial photograph (or a scanned map, etc.) to your GIS mapping. Georeferencer is not automatic. It relies on you manually choosing points to register.

The operation of this tool is documented at
http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_georeferencer.html

However here is a summary. In your example screnshot, it would appear that you know where the corner points of the aerial photograph 'should' be in your GIS map. So you would open the aerial photograph image and, one by one, at each corner of the image, 'add point', referencing each point to where you think it should be on your GIS map.

Once you have got an initial result, you can add other points later to refine the georeferencing by aligning recognisable features such as road intersections to where you believe they should be on the map, and run Georeferencer again.

Because aerial photographs have lens distortion, you may find that setting the Transformation type to 'thin plate spline' and Resampling to 'Cubic' gives the best results; these are the settings for full 'rubbersheeting'.

Whatever it is that you are currently doing, start again and follow the documented procedure. Georeferencer is a reliable and powerful tool, and not likely to fail.